# Inifinite loop after CAS certificate change

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, cas, http-redirect

I am writing to check if anyone has had a similar issue with Jasig CAS.

We are basic facing infinite redirects in the browser (In firefox: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.") after being able to log in CAS. It seems the client side does not get properly the authentication details ?

Since we have not done any code change, I think this is because a certificate change we did last night. We had a new ssl certificate from Verisign which we are using in all our servers., matching the server against our root domain.

Verisign certificate seem correct, and also intermediate ones... 
Don't know if the old certificate could be cached somewhere in CAS or what could be the problem as to why the client and cas keep redirecting themselves, all only after we uploaded the new certificate into the Load Balancer (as the old one was expired).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

My guess would be that the new certificate, even if it works properly from a browser, doesn't work properly for a direct call directly from the application in the JVM (bad intermediate certificate for example). So, the service ticket validation fails and if the error page is protected, the user is sent to the CAS server which redirects him back to the application for service ticket validation and so on. Thus, the infinite loop...